# Using fadeIn() and fadeOut() successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I have a grid of items, some of which are images, and some are text (all vertically-aligned, using different CSS techniques). Clicking these hides the content with `fadeOut()`, and shows different content with `fadeIn()`.

My question is two-part:

How can I get the initially-hidden content to **not** match the CSS of the front during the transition? The text is mis-aligned until the transition has finished.

And secondly, how can I toggle this switch so that the process can be reversed?

My CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #dddddd;
    margin: 10px;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 124px;
    max-width: 124px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.inner p {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.back {
    display: none;
}
```

And my JavaScript/jQuery so far:

```
$(".outer").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".front").fadeOut();
    $(this).find(".back").fadeIn();
});
```

[A JSFiddle of my predicament can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/bw7s3pxe/1/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should fade the element `.back` in *after*  the element `.front` has been faded out.

You would do this by invoking `.fadeIn()` within the `.fadeOut()` callback:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyc2dL4o/)

```
$(".outer").click(function () {
    var self = this;
    $(this).find(".front").fadeOut(function () {
        $(self).find(".back").fadeIn();
    });
});
```